# Jquery TokenInput : Delete token when token limit is one by DELETE button

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jquery token input control,when token limit is set to one i want to delete it by selecting the token then press delete button (and not clicking the x button), any help in acheiving this??

Comment: do u have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: The question is too vague.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far